# Extract SNPs from multiple sequence alignment

Tags: sequence-alignment, phylogenetics, variants

I’m wondering if folks have recommendations for tools/scripts to extract SNP sites from a multiple sequence alignment of consensus bacterial genomes? Specifically, I am interested in a multiple sequence alignment containing variant (SNP) positions only, to be used as input for phylogeny-building programs including RAxML and BEAST.

I was previously using https://github.com/sanger-pathogens/snp-sites, but this is not being maintained and I’m running into errors that it seems many others are having (with regards to sequences being different lengths, although I have confirmed they are the same length).

Any recommendations would be great, thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you looking for identity, or are you variant calling, or finally perhaps looking a consensus sequence?

Comment: Yes, apologies for the lack of clarity. I have aligned consensus sequences, I'm hoping to extract SNP sites only into an alignment of SNP positions. Thank you!